# Why do i get time out in bluemix sample app?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud

I have followed the tutorial of bluemix that is called bluelist. See here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-mobiledata-app/#N1021F

I have installed all required libs and i have installed everything in the bluemix side.

I get error IBMBLUEMIX-0554E: timeout expired before connection could be established.

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by a couple issues.

1. You could be attempting to access an internal test zone (AKA stage1) without being in the internal network. Make sure there is not stage1 present in your app route.
2. Your phone/emulator may not be connected to a network properly. Please be sure that your test device is connected to the internet via data service or local connection. You can try running a speed test on that device if in doubt. Some custom created emulators can also have issues of their own. Try using a physical device if possible.
3. You may be on a network using a proxy server. I have heard of timeout issues when using a proxy. You may need to use a network that does not utilize a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes intermittently some times due to network/connectivity issue.Also you need to Verify that your applicationId, applicationSecret, and applicationRoute are correct.You can go to the Overview of your Mobile Cloud Service application on ACE to find your applicationId and Route. The applicationSecret is on the MAS portion of the ACE UI for your application.
Similar issue was reported already:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/26821/getting-time-out-error-while-conencting-to-mobile-cloud-bluemix-application.html